# How to preserve a database connection pool in hooks.server.js during hot reload in SvelteKit with Vite.js and mariadb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite, sveltekit

I am using [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/), [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev/), and the [`mariadb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb) package with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en) in my application. I have the following code in the `db.js` file:

```js
import mariadb from 'mariadb';

const databaseConnectionPoolConfig = {
  ...
};

let databaseConnectionPool = undefined;

export function createDatabaseConnectionPool() {
  return databaseConnectionPool ??= mariadb.createPool(databaseConnectionPoolConfig);
}
```

Inside the `hooks.server.js` file, I have the following code:

```js
import { createDatabaseConnectionPool } from '$lib/db';

createDatabaseConnectionPool();
```

When a hot reload is performed, the `databaseConnectionPool` is reset to undefined, but the connections in the pool are not closed, and new ones are created. I checked this by running the following query:

```sql
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Threads_connected';
```

Which increases each time a hot reload is performed by the number of connections specified by the `databaseConnectionPoolConfig.connectionLimit` property.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the `globalThis` object. The `globalThis` object doesn't get reset when hot reloads occur, which allows the database connection pool to be preserved. Here's the solution I've come up with:

```js
// hooks.server.js

globalThis.databaseConnectionPool ??= mariadb.createPool(databaseConnectionPoolConfig);
```

Comment: Do you mean `globalThis`? [Global is legacy](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html). See my [updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77165280/6309).

Comment: @VonC Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm looking for a clear, step-by-step solution to maintain a database connection pool while performing a hot reload in SvelteKit with Vite.js and MariaDB.
>
> Currently, the problem is that the connection pool is reset to undefined with each hot reload, resulting in new connections.

You would need to implement a mechanism to persist the database connection pool across hot reloads.

In your `db.js` file, change the `createDatabaseConnectionPool` function to check if the global variable `global.databaseConnectionPool` exists before creating a new pool.

Since [NodeJS global](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#global) is "legacy", consider [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)

```js
import mariadb from 'mariadb';

const databaseConnectionPoolConfig = {
  // ...your existing config
};

export function createDatabaseConnectionPool() {
  if (globalThis.databaseConnectionPool) {
    return globalThis.databaseConnectionPool;
  }
  
  globalThis.databaseConnectionPool = mariadb.createPool(databaseConnectionPoolConfig);
  return globalThis.databaseConnectionPool;
}
```

That will allow you to store a single instance of the database connection pool in a global variable that will not be reset upon hot reloads.

Then:

- Run your [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) application.
- Perform a hot reload by modifying some code.
- Run the SQL query `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Threads_connected';` again to check if the number of threads connected increases or not.

By doing this, you should be able to maintain the same database connection pool even after multiple hot reloads, provided your development environment does not clear `require.cache` on a hot reload.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. I tested it, and whenever I try to run the code, I get an error saying: `Internal server error: require is not defined`. I assume this is because I use ES modules, not CommonJS modules.

Comment: The updated answer works. Thanks!